# How to get install.wim from windows 10 pro installation file

Tags: windows, deployment

I am currently learning windows 10 deploy. I have Microsoft Deployment toolkit update 2013 update 1 installed. When I try to import operating system, system tell me can not find install.wim in windows sources. I did some research found out that current windows 10 home/pro installation media comes with install.esd instead install.wim. Is there anyone know to to extract install.wim from install.esd. I have looked at few ways online, none of them working.

Answer (score 8):

You can easily convert install.esd to install.wim using [ESD2WIM-WIM2ESD.cmd](https://gist.github.com/armujahid/8f861b17a110854d0b7db38d7349cee6)

1. Run it as Administrator
2. Enter location of install.esd
3. Type 1 and it will start converting
4. Once that is done you should see the completed install.wim in the same directory in which this cmd utility is located

Reference:
http://markthetech.com/how-to-convert-install-esd-to-install-wim/

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if they just used  install.wim in the first place lol

Comment: @Chockomonkey windows 10 installation media doesn't have install.wim. That's the whole point of this question.

Comment: I just mean that since dism is able to read esd files as wim files, and they both play the same role for the installation media, either microsoft should have added support for the esd version of the install file in MDT, or just stuck with the wim extention

Answer (score 4):

You can use dism to convert the install.esd from the Media Creation Tool to an install.wim.

```
dism /export-image /sourceimagefile:c:\path\to\install.esd /destinationimagefile:c:\path\to\install.wim /compress:max /checkintegrity
```

The install.esd file could contain a few different versions of windows, so you may need the source index for this to work. To find the appropriate index, run:

```
dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:c:\path\to\install.esd
```

Then add the /sourceindex:# for the version of window you need:

```
dism /export-image /sourceimagefile:c:\path\to\install.esd /sourceindex:6 /destinationimagefile:c:\path\to\install.wim /compress:max /checkintegrity
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the WIM file from any media other than the Media Creation Tool download (or Windows Update). You could also use the Media Creation Tool installation media on a virtual machine and then Sysprep and capture from that VM.

Media downloaded from MSDN or VLSC will contain a WIM and have no issues with MDT.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the official Windows 10 ISO image from Microsoft by visiting:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO

But you must be on Linux (or pretend to be using user agent switcher) to download the file.

The install file is an ISO file and it contains the`install.wim` file you are looking for.

Source: [tqdev.com](https://tqdev.com/2016-creating-bootable-windows-10-usb-ubuntu)